# How to use PDO for database-specific functions?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, abstraction

I need to use specific functions in MySQL which I'm not sure is available in other DB flavors. E.g.,

`SELECT DATE_SUB(mydate, INTERVAL 5 DAY) AS foo FROM table`

What is the best practice for cases like this when using PDO?

Edit:

What I mean to ask is, how can I make sure `DATE_SUB` will also work in all DB flavors that supports PDO?

Comment: How is pdo supposed to make your database statements any bit easier/simpler or whatever you seem to be asking?

Comment: You can use `$pdo->query("Your sql")`, i'm not sure that is what you want. But it's work.

Comment: This is a very poorly-worded question, it can not be understood, voting to close

Comment: I am not sure how this question is unclear when the top voted/accepted answer gets it like a boss.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how can I make sure DATE_SUB will also work in all DB flavors that supports PDO?

You can't.

If you want a database-independent layer, look at the [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)

Answer (score 2):

PDO will abstract connectivity with your database but it doesn't do anything for the SQL statements, apart from adding support for prepared statements for all DBMS.

DBMS specific functions (e.g. `DATE_SUB()` in MySQL) and SQL versions are therefore fine with that specific DBMS (e.g. MySQL) but aren't emulated for other DBMS (e.g. MS SQL server).

To quote the PHP/PDO [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php):

> PDO provides a data-access abstraction layer, which means that, regardless of which database you're using, you use the same functions to issue queries and fetch data. **PDO does not provide a database abstraction; it doesn't rewrite SQL or emulate missing features.** You should use a full-blown abstraction layer if you need that facility.